# JQuery Mobile pop up, weird text rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Copy and pasted demo Jquery mobile pop up code from here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/#&ui-state=dialog and I get this weird rendering of ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃ (see picture)

Any reason why?

[image]

Comment: Check the page's encoding. Try to set it to utf-8 or Unicode.

Comment: @ForceBru thank you that worked. Added this line: " <meta charset="UTF-8">" and it fixed it. If you make it an answer I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the encoding of your page, such as `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. 'Garbage characters' appear because your page has an encoding that your browser cannot guess.